# Change frames in Actions

Tags: actions

How do I extend/reduce key frames in the action editor. This is a character I have entered into blender from Mixamo, Sometimes I want to edit the keys for a character, how do I do so here?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Press <kbd>tab</kbd> in the *NLA* window so that you get access to the keyframes of your strip in the *Dopesheet*, then <kbd>tab</kbd> again to come back to the normal strip behavior.